# How to use a consumer key and consumer secret key to access multiple API's?

Tags: apigee

Currently, I am using Apigee API with token that is generated by using consumer key and consumer secret key. This access token is used as 'Authorization Bearer' while calling API. I am calling API like following:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer mytoken" 'http://{my-org}-test.apigee.net/v1/{api}/getData'
```

Following is my scenario:

There are multiple customers who wants to get data using different API's. I want to use one consumer key and consumer secret key for multiple API's per customer.

Is there any way to achieve my objective using 'Apigee API'?

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apigee out of the box supports this functionality using concept called API Product. You will bundle multiple APIs, API resources into a product called API Product. API keys are always associated with Apps / API Products than APIs itself.

An API product is a collection of API resources (URIs) combined with a service plan and presented to developers as a bundle.

You can find more about API Products here. See more about creating API products here. Keep us posted if you have any queries.

Let me try to explain this with an example,

Let's say I am running a Telco business & I have many services to offer. I would like to open up my business using APIs so that I can reach out to large developer base as well as quickly expand my business in today's integrations world like onboarding partners, customers, developers etc into my business.

I have following services that i would like to expose , let's say

1. SMS Services
2. Location Services

I will create following apis,

SMS :

1. Send SMS : POST : http://mytelcom.com/sms
2. Get SMS Details : GET : http://mytelcom.com/sms/{SMSID}

Location Services :

```
Update Location : POST : http://mytelecom.com/location/{MOBILENUMBER}
Get Location : GET : http://mytelecom.com/location/{MOBILENUMBER}
```

Let's say, now, i would like to provide access to all APIs to my internal team, i will create an API Product called "Unlimited API" & i will add all above APIs to the API Product list.

Let's say, I would like to provide only READ access to my services to my partner, i can create a product called, "PARTNER API" and add only GET SMS Details API, GET Location API Details API to the api product.

I will create a developer app for my internal team called "Internal App" & choose "Unlimited API" product while creating APP. When you are done with creating an APP, you will be provided with Consumer Key & Secret Key using which you can access the APIs that has been configured in the product. Apigee Edge Platform handles these restrictions out of the box.

Similar to above, Either you will create Apps for your partner / restrict your partner to certain API products while creating developer apps which in turn restricts to certain API proxies.